# Как из строки получить номера

Tags: c#

```
var response = await _client.GetAsync($"http://tr.ru/api/SMSService/GeService?code={1234}");
    
var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

в responseString записано:

```
"{\"lastActivationDate\":\"2018-11-06T00:00:00\",\
"accounts\":
    [
        {\"bankAccount\":\"700\",\"bankCode\":\"22\",\"currency\":\"EUR\",\"messageType\":7,\"phone1\":\"9955028\",\"numberFormat1\":\"1\",\"numberFormat2\":\"-1\",\"activeStatus\":1},
        {\"bankAccount\":\"70\",\"bankCode\":\"22\",\"currency\":\"USD\",\"messageType\":7,\"phone1\":\"9950028\",\"numberFormat1\":\"1\",\"numberFormat2\":\"-1\",\"activeStatus\":1}
    ]
    ,\"message\":{\"successful\":true,\"code\":0,\"errorText\":\"\",\"response\":0}}"
```

хочу с responseString взять только уникальные номера, как это сделать?

Comment: сначала взять все номера, а потом отфильтровать те у которых есть дубликаты) С чем именно возникают проблемы?

Comment: @Andrew не могу взять номера

Comment: если тебе нужны ВСЕ номера а не с какого-то конкретного параметра - используй регулярные выражения. Если нужно по параметрам - сначала спарсь в обьекты твой JSON

Comment: Вам надо научиться парсить json файл, иначе могут возникнуть проблемы что вам нужны не все цифры, а только допустим, номера банковских счетов или только номера телефонов.